# Red5-Recorder not working

Tags: red5

I have done with red5 server installation.everything works fine in server installation..all the demo red5 applications are working perfectly. but I'm getting problem with red5-recorder..I'm getting an ERROR:could not connect to the server rtmp://127.0.0.1 ..Is there any other modification I have to do in the code?

Answer (score 2):

ERROR:could not connect to the server rtmp://127.0.0.1 is caused by

if(Application.application.parameters.server!=null) myRecorder.server= Application.application.parameters.server;

which defaults to nc.connect(myRecorder.server) which returns 127.0.0.1/red5recorder

In order to get around this, you can pass along the server= FlashVar.

Edit red5recorder.html and add this in the appropriate place (after line #91):

"FlashVars", "server=rtmp://your.external.server.ip/red5recorder"

This is because the swf is downloaded and run client side, and needs to connect to your server's RTMP service. It can't connect to 127.0.0.1/red5recorder because that's your PC. This is why you set the server= paramerter. :-)

I hope that helps.

Comment: This did not work for me. It still comes up with error message.

Comment: Could you show the error messages as well as the exact steps you took?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new web app for Red5Recorder as indicates [here](http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/newapp.html) with the name "**red5recorder**" because that's the name the recorder use to comunicate with. (see the Recorder.as file in the sources) and after restarted the server it started to work. The output file called "video.flv" is in the streams/ subdirectory.
I hope this helps you.
 Cristian